# Tinymce Error - Failed to load plugin js files when dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm trying to load TinyMCE dynamically like so (on clicking a button):

```
$.getScript('path/to/mce4/tinymce.min.js', function(){
    var def = {
        selector: 'textarea',
        body_class: 'sp-mce-editor',
        content_css : "path/to/styles/mce.css",
        plugins: ['advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code insertdatetime media nonbreaking table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor fullscreen autoresize'],
        toolbar: "bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor | preview fullscreen | template",
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',
        relative_urls : false,
        convert_urls : true,
        external_plugins: { "nanospell": "path/to/mce4/nanospell/plugin.js" },
        nanospell_server:"php",
        file_browser_callback: RoxyFileBrowser,
        init_instance_callback: (typeof processEditor != 'undefined' ? processEditor : null)
   };


    tinymce.init(def);
});
```

With this configuration, tinyMCE fails to initialize. In the console I see several 404 errors, each with a message like this:

```
Failed to load: /path/to/mce4/plugins/textcolor/plugin.js
```

Sure on checking in the console the JS file `tinymce.min.js` loads correctly. Also, the `/path/to/mce4/plugins/textcolor/plugin.js` does not exist. But `/path/to/mce4/plugins/textcolor/plugin.min.js` exists, and this is true for all the js files involved (i.e. the `.min.js` files are there, but tinyMCE for whatever reason is looking for the `.js` files).

Now, when I load tinyMCE in a script tab in the `<head>`, there's no problem at all, and everything works well.

What could be causing this error, and how am I supposed to fix it? If this is the expected behaviour of tinyMCE, what is the correct way to dynamically load its js file for the scenario such as I am working on?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using angular2+ with angular-cli, following might help you.
Lets say you want to add a plugin named `autoresize`. Check if this plugin is present in `node_modules/tinymce/plugins`. If yes, do following:

1.**In angular-cli.json**:

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.js",
       **"../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/autoresize/plugin.js",/add this/**
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

2.**In the intializing component:**

```
tinymce.init({

     ...
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table','**autoresize**'],
      autoresize_bottom_margin: 50,//this is plug in requirement
      ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you what is wrong with your code, but this works for me (TinyMCE 4.x)

I put the path to tinymce.min.js like this:

```
<script src="/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

So it loads with the page load. Not to be loaded dynamically.

Then I made a function defined:

```
function IactivateMCE() {
   tinymce.init({
     selector: "div.c10",
     code continue
   })
}
```

Then I made a onclick that run: IactivateMCE() AFTER the dynamic content had been added to the site ( I have a function that first add dynamic content to the site, then initialize TinyMCE).

Hope this can benefit you :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course I know your pattern works, and in fact use it that way elsewhere in the application. But you'd agree with me that there are scenarios where loading dynamically brings along certain advantages. That's where this question falls into

Comment: I don't see why you'd like to load tinymce.min.js dynamically. But if you do that is more of a question as how to load any javascript dynamically after the page has loaded. Right? The init you have to load dynamically after the new content has been added, and that can be easily done as mentioned.